# ReportNG - How to attach screenshot in the Report generated by reportng usingTestNG Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng, reportng

This question will seem repetitive but I couldn't find the workable solution to this.

I need to attach a screenshot in the report generated using reportng listeners. How to attach passed or failed screenshot against each test

I think ReportNG provides the best report out of all the available reports including extent report. Extent report seems a bit hyped to me as I don't get all the details that are present in the reportng.

Comment: I recommend you [Allure 2](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2) for your report. It is easy to add screenshots and your own needs as plugins.

Comment: Thanks j.barrio, I'll try to find any tutorial on Allure2 and see if it fits my requirements.

Comment: I put the link to the github and there you have a link to the [last version](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/) of the user manual.

Comment: What details dont you get with extent? We switched from reportng for the very reason of not getting the details we wanted.. have you also seen it's server Klov? That is our primary reporting tool.

Comment: Hi Karthik I want the following from a report
1. Tabular format of execution report
2. Report should list down the execution logs on a different page
3. Report should show the data providers and all parameters used to test a particular test case
4. Report should show the assert errors with expand/collapse button instead of showing the big full trace on assertion error
5. link to screenshot for the failed scenarios against the respective tests
Can you show me sample extent report having above all ? Only thing I am not able to implement in reportng is point 5 above

Comment: Hi J.Barrio, in the documentation, I don't see the installation instructions for TestNG only as I am not using Maven, it talks about TestNG with Maven, do you know any documentation where it talks about Allure installation with only TestNg?

Comment: I don't see much support and tutorials on Maven on the internet, not sure if my questions will be answered if I come across any issues later ? I don't want to switch to extent reports but don't see any other option now

Comment: What technologies do you use in your test? Only libraries?

Comment: We don't have any build tool as of now, build is done by another team, so we are just creating framework without any build tool like Maven, Gradle, we are just using TestNG and nothing else

Comment: I tried to install Maven but because of network security I am not able to create Maven project and I am not sure how to bypass the network firewall with proxy as I am not sure about my proxy host and port. Lots of issues

Comment: You can implement all 5 items and more with Extent easily in my opinion..